# Deleting a indexDB database in firefox

Tags: firefox, indexeddb

I'm having a bit of hard time totally deleting an unwanted indexDB database. My workflow is I press a submit button and a check is done for a stored key in the DB.

The problem I have if user accidentally clicks Submit before the key in the store has been added FF does not fail like chrome does but instead creates a sort of zombie DB that I can't remove. Here's what it looks like from Dev tools:

[image]

Subsequent to this action if I try to add the key to the DB I get a "the DB cant be mutated in present state" etc. the only way to add a key is to then right click on local host in dev tools and delete the DB. Not practical to ask of a user.  I would love to be able to check for an empty store before trying to create a DB but apparently FF creates a DB even if it fails to open a new DB successfully.
here's my code:

```
/**
 * @Description - create a new IndexedDB db.
 * @returns db - a reference to the indexedDB object.
 */
async function createDB() {
  const db = await openDB(dbName, version, {
    // Optional. Only called if a version mismatch
    /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
    upgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion, transaction) {
      const store = db.createObjectStore(storeName);
    },
  });

  return db;
}
```

Is there anyway to delete a DB fully?